# What is the name of this metric?

Tags: classification, terminology, metric

In a binary classification problem, the metric of: `FP/(FP+FN)`

Is there an established name for this? Or for the analogous version with FN in the numerator?

Comment: out of curiosity, why would you want to calculate it? After some googling I found Boehm 2013 https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/11156515.pdf calling it false positive rate, however this is wrong https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positive_rate

Comment: @rep_ho "Wrong" seems a poor choice of words here. The false positive rate in the Wikipedia article has limited adoption. Moreover, in probability "rates" are always contextualized by the definition of event occurrence out of a particular population. That someone wants to think of a "false positive rate" out of all false test decisions seems a reasonable use of language.

Comment: @Alexis sure, there is nothing about the word 'rate' that would make it one way or another, but with respect to other used measures the usage in the paper is non-standard. TPR is commonly used and has P in the denominator, so then I would also expect false positive rate to have either P or N in the denominator. It also makes sense that FPR is 1-TNR, but this wouldn't be the case if its defined otherwise.

Comment: @rep_ho "Non standard" I do not think there ***is*** a standard usage... that is what I am saying.

Comment: There is a wikipedia page with several metrics : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity . Yours does not appear in there and I don't think I ever encountered it as most of the time we want info of the number of errors compared to the number of accurate predictions.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not, at least according to what I could find in Google and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix).

I would argue that, while that can be an interesting metric to characterize errors, it does not convey any new information that the habitual metrics didn't already.

Comment: I think we can just call it Mitrano's measure from now on

Answer (score 1):

I once (can't remember when or where) saw a journal article in which authors called it "harmfulness". In that article `FP` was "worse kind of error" than `FN` (it had something to do with amputations). So `FP/(FP+FN)` was measuring how harmfull a diagnostic method is when it actually "makes" a mistake.